# rsyslog not starting up: not found

Tags: rsyslog

When starting rsyslog I get the following:

```
/etc/init.d/rsyslog: 1: /etc/default/rsyslog: imudp: not found
/etc/init.d/rsyslog: 2: /etc/default/rsyslog: 127.0.0.1: not found
/etc/init.d/rsyslog: 3: /etc/default/rsyslog: 514: not found
```

My /etc/default/rsyslog file:

```
$ModLoad imudp
$UDPServerAddress 127.0.0.1
$UDPServerRun 514
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after running an update on Ubuntu 14.04. My guess is that */etc/init.d/rsyslog* is outdated, because /*etc/rsyslog.conf* has exactly the same configuration with the individual rules below */etc/rsyslog.d/*. So all I did to fix this was to check that */etc/rsyslog.conf* contained what I wanted and then I removed the lines from */etc/init.d/rsyslog* followed by a service restart.